# How can I draw a custom horizontal line with jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

[image: target image mockup]

The pink line is what I'd like to add, to emphazise a certain percentage value. Is it possible with jqplot and how would this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `canvasOverlay` for jqplot to draw custom lines or other objects on your graph.
Please follow the link and here you can learn about how to use canvasOverlay.
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html